# Distinct Conditional Group By Month to Quarter : Inclusive or Any?

Tags: sql, group-by, ssms

```
select store,fiscalquarter
,count(distinct case when trxcount>=2 then clubno end) as clubcountfreq
,count(distinct clubno ) as clubcountall from(

select 
store,clubno,monthname,fiscalquarter, count(distinct trxid) trxcount 

from 
server.saleslog sh
    left join server.datelookup dd
    on sh.dateid=dd.dateid

where 
store in (439,237)
    and
clubno is not null
    and
fiscalquarter between '202201' and '202204'

group by store,clubno, monthname,fiscalquarter
) a  

group by store,fiscalquarter
order by store,fiscalquarter asc
```

As the internal function creates a monthly transaction count per customer, the outside function groups these months to the quarter level, will the

```
,count(distinct case when trxcount>=2 then clubno end) as clubcountfreq
```

evaluate a customer as included if they are >=2 in all 3 months of the quarter?
or bc there is a 'distinct' outside the 'case when', does it only need to be >=2 in only 1 month?

**How would one find 'only if >=2 in all 3 months' from this example?**

Pretty sure it's only evaluating as >=2 in a single of the 3 months since it only trims to distinct after the case when is complete.

I'm leaning towards just pulling if their average is 2x+/month, or >=6 total/qtr to avoid having to parse through how to do only >=2/month in all months/qtr. That includes a handful of fringe cases though that could be argued to be useful or biasing depending on the use case.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as tabular text. You might also want to reduce the number of questions in your post and describe a more specific problem statement.

Comment: nah i'm good, thx